# Scala: Implementing a generic fold

Tags: scala

I don't understand why thid fold doesn't compile. Could anyone give me a clue?

```
sealed trait ListG[A] {

  def fold[A,B](end: B, f: (A,B) => B): B = this match {
    case End() => end
    case Cons(hd,tl) => f(hd, tl.fold(end,f))
  }
}
```

Error:(20, 28) type mismatch;
 found   : hd.type (with underlying type A)
 required: A
    case Cons(hd,tl) => f(hd, tl.fold(end,f))
                          ^
    final case class EndA extends ListG[A]
    final case class Cons[A](hd:A, tl:ListG[A]) extends ListG[A]

Comment: post the error message along with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding type ascription appears to fix the problem.

```
case Cons(hd:A, tl) => ...
            ^^
```

There is a warning about type erasure but it does compile and appears to run.

Answer (score 5):

You're shadowing type parameter `A` of `ListG` when you define an additional type parameter `A` on the `fold` function.